# CHECK Constraint to enforce upper case letter and pattern match

Tags: sql-server, database-design, check-constraints

For one of my columns I am trying to enforce a pattern. The first letter should be `D` upper case, and the remaining 3 characters should be digits. For example:

`D678`, `D890`, `D000`

I'm quite new with `CHECK` constraints  and things like regular expressions.

Below is what I've done so far, which (I think) enforces the general pattern. However when I try adding something like `d900` it works, even though it's a lower case d. I expected this to fail.

Can someone please assist:

```
CREATE TABLE Systems(
SystemsID NVARCHAR(4),
Title NVARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT chk_SystemsID CHECK (SystemsID LIKE '[D][0-9][0-9][0-9]'));
```

Comment: A tangent to your question but you should just use `D` not `[D]`

Comment: Shouldn't `SystemsID` be declared `NCHAR(4)` or even `CHAR(4)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the database and column collations are case-insensitive so the `LIKE` expression is also case-insensitive.

One way to perform a case-sensitive compare in this scenario is by adding a `COLLATE` clause, specifying a case-sensitive collation. For example, if your database default collation is a case insensitive collation such as Latin1_General_CI_AS, the example below will override that collation with the case-sensitive version of the collation for the literal and perform the case-sensitive comparison you want:

```
CREATE TABLE Systems(
    SystemsID NVARCHAR(4),
    Title NVARCHAR(30),
    CONSTRAINT chk_SystemsID CHECK (SystemsID LIKE '[D][0-9][0-9][0-9]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
);
```

Below are related collation documentation pages for your perusal:

- [COLLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Collation Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I'll give this a try. I've not come across `COLLATE` yet so I'll need to look into that first.

Comment: @AaronWright, I added documentation links to my answer for your review.